# Remove border around JavaFX ScrollPane scroll bar when *not* focused

Tags: css, javafx

I have a strange issue. I've styled the scroll-bar of my ScrollPane in JavaFX using CSS, but now every time the ScrollPane is *in focus*, the border disappears. However, if I click a button outside of the pane, it comes back. 
Here are the images: 
**Unfocused**
[image: Unfocused]
**Focused**
[image: Focused]
Here is the CSS:

```css
.scroll-bar:horizontal .track,
.scroll-bar:vertical .track{
    -fx-background-color :transparent;
    -fx-border-color :transparent;
    -fx-background-radius : 2.0em;
}

.scroll-bar:horizontal .increment-button ,
.scroll-bar:horizontal .decrement-button {
    -fx-background-color :transparent;
    -fx-background-radius : 0.0em;
    -fx-padding :0.0 0.0 10.0 0.0;

}

.scroll-bar:vertical .track-background,
.scroll-bar:horizontal .track-background {
   -fx-background-color: transparent;
   -fx-background-insets: 0;
   -fx-background-radius: 2em;
}

.scroll-bar:vertical .increment-button ,
.scroll-bar:vertical .decrement-button {
    -fx-background-color :transparent;
    -fx-background-radius : 0.0em;
    -fx-padding :0.0 10.0 0.0 0.0;

}

.scroll-bar .increment-arrow,
.scroll-bar .decrement-arrow{
    -fx-shape : " ";
    -fx-padding :0.15em 0.0;
}

.scroll-bar:vertical .increment-arrow,
.scroll-bar:vertical .decrement-arrow{
    -fx-shape : " ";
    -fx-padding :0.0 0.15em;
}

.scroll-bar:horizontal .thumb,
.scroll-bar:vertical .thumb {
    -fx-background-color : #dddddd;
    -fx-background-insets : 2.0, 0.0, 0.0;
    -fx-background-radius : 2.0em;
}

.scroll-bar:horizontal .thumb:hover,
.scroll-bar:vertical .thumb:hover {
    -fx-background-color : #9e9e9e;
    -fx-background-insets : 2.0, 0.0, 0.0;
    -fx-background-radius : 2.0em;
}

.scroll-bar{
   -fx-background-color: transparent;
   -fx-background-radius: 2em;
   -fx-focus-color: transparent;
   -fx-faint-focus-color: transparent;
}

.scroll-bar:vertical:focused {
   -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `-fx-focus-color` and playing around with insets in the `.scroll-bar` class (the regular one, not the `:focused` pseudo-class):

```
.scroll-bar {
    -fx-focus-color: transparent;
    -fx-background-insets: -1.4, 0, 1, 2;
}
```